# How to calculate time in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My webapplication is online exam site. when user click on start for writing test, i have to restrict the user particular time only, after time is completed message should display to the user  that your exam time is finished and he redirect to home page, how can i write the code, can i go for timer control or webservice which one is good for the online exam site, please help me.

Comment: You need to use client side timer, it's not really possible with server side code unless you're using AJAX which is pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to capture the time when the user starts the test inside a Session variable:

```
 Session["StartTime"] = DateTime.Now;// when user start test
```

Then when you postback the page get the difference between the current time and the time you stored in the Session:

```
diffrencebetweentime = DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(Session["StartTime"]); // at every postback
```

If the time difference is more than what you have decided send user to home page.

Comment: Cheers, I fixed some more grammar problems, hope it makes sense and that you'll also apply this in future answers.